# VPS, Apache MySql and phpMyadmin error

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

Recently I have configured VPS but it doesnt work well.

Whats problem ? I installed Apache2, MySql, PHP, using yum install and i installed phpmyadmin from source compiled it basicly i followed tutorials online.

When I try to make phpmyadmin work on ssh i enter 'service httpd restart' It gives me this error

```
[root@localhost ~]# service httpd restart
Stopping httpd:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting httpd: [Fri Oct 04 13:43:08 2013] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf at line 9 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
[Fri Oct 04 13:43:08 2013] [warn] The Alias directive in /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf at line 10 will probably never match because it overlaps an earlier Alias.
```

PHP version

```
PHP 5.5.4 (cli) (built: Sep 19 2013 15:01:01)
```

MYSQL version

```
mysql  Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.5.34, for Linux (i686) using readline 5.1
```

I dont know how to fix it when I try to access phpmyadmin it gives me 403 ERROR

I hope someone can help me fix it

On server there is installed centos 5.8

Thanks in advance :)

EDIT:

phpmyadmin.conf

```
#
# Web application to manage MySQL
#
#<Directory "/usr/share/phpmyadmin">
# Order Deny,Allow
# Deny from all
# Allow from 127.0.0.1
#</Directory>
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
Alias /mysqladmin /usr/share/phpmyadmin
```

Comment: This should be moved to serverfault it isn't a programming problem

Comment: Look at the file /etc/httpd/conf.d/phpmyadmin.conf, especially rows 9 and 10. Are the aliases there just like an alias in the first 8 rows?

Comment: I edited post you can see how phpmyadmin.conf looks like

Comment: Check the .htaccess files and the httpd.conf, or anything in httpd/conf to make sure those aliases don't already exist

Answer (score 2):

This question is 4 years old at my writing - and i did not notice that at first -  but for those who come along . . . late like me

Anyone needs to start with an install of CentOS 7 - or get rid of or pass on  any hosting company if they do not have it.  The update life ended 31 March 2017 of CentOS 5.x

do not build from source - configure the REMI repository - it has phpmyadmin in the latest version and configured php installs to CentOS standards.  Between yum update and the proper epel release - installing phpmyadmin is simple.

See https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/  Remi is also a regular support contributor at CentOS.org - but NO ONE will help with CentOS 5.8 it is just way too old, and most won't help with CentOS 6 now at this writing - either.  There is no "upgrade" path if you start with CentOS 6, you MUST start with CentOS 7 and it then has an upgrade path from there on.

A better web server to use is from codeit - it has http2 and is updated more frequently than the redhat version and it is the Red Hat / Centos file version of etc/httpd of Apache.  It will get you an "A" at SSLLABS.com.

Also CentOS now has MariaDB and not MySQL - which would be 10.1.xx or 10.2.xx - not 5.xx   Upgrade to 10.2 - it has dynamic Innodb pool sizing and launches in a smaller memory footprint.

Then Get a panel like Webmin for operating on the server itself and use WinSCP if you access it with a Windows client. Once you get it configured Webmin will automatically keep your system sane and up to date.  Webmin has a yum repo too that can be configured.  there are some repos to STAY AWAY from => see https://wiki.centos.org/AdditionalResources/Repositories

No one today is doing themselves any favors even trying to run even CentOS 6 for that matter

So to answer the question for any late comers - here is what a good phpmyadmin conf file looks like and it locks out anyone but the network you come in on - it would be in /etc/httpd/conf.d if you have a properly set up Red Hat style CentOS server - but "apache2 is NOT what would known as - so it sounds like you may have made a Frankenstein server.  The error message tells me that.  somewhere an alias is already loaded.  try to stay away from compiling anything yourself - on CentOS - most of he time an RPM or repo has the file - search the web for the rpm - then see if there is a yum repo you can configure

The remi phpmyadmin comes with a good conf file like this one below - but without the IP require statements

If you see something on the web - as a tutorial and it is not for CentOS and YOUR version - move one and do not try to use it.

```
# phpMyAdmin - Web based MySQL browser written in php
# 
# Allows only localhost by default
#
# But allowing phpMyAdmin to anyone other than localhost should be considered
# dangerous unless properly secured by SSL

Alias /phpMyAdmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin
Alias /phpmyadmin /usr/share/phpMyAdmin

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
    AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
  # Require local
     <RequireAny>
       Require all denied
       Require ip (your ip or subnet - it will take ranges like xxc.xxx.0.0/16)
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
   </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
    </IfModule>
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/>
   <IfModule mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.4
     # Require local
     <RequireAny>
       Require all denied
       Require ip (your ip or subnet - it will tke ranges like xxc.xxx.0.0/16)
       Require ip 127.0.0.1
       Require ip ::1
     </RequireAny>
    </IfModule>
   <IfModule !mod_authz_core.c>
     # Apache 2.2
     Order Deny,Allow
     Deny from All
     Allow from 127.0.0.1
     Allow from ::1
   </IfModule>
</Directory>

# These directories do not require access over HTTP - taken from the original
# phpMyAdmin upstream tarball
#
<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/libraries/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/lib/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

<Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/setup/frames/>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from All
    Allow from None
</Directory>

# This configuration prevents mod_security at phpMyAdmin directories from
# filtering SQL etc.  This may break your mod_security implementation.
#
<IfModule mod_security.c>
    <Directory /usr/share/phpMyAdmin/>
        SecRuleInheritance Off
    </Directory>
</IfModule>
```

Do not embarrass yourself making a Frankenstein server - make a current server under CentOS 7 and keep it current with yum and you can then get people to possibly help and it will run right

Answer (score 1):

I'm wondering why you didn't install phpmyadmin from the repository directly?

```
yum install phpmyadmin
```

Regards

Comment: Becouse i got errors everytime i try to install it cant get it working  I dont know why It always fails If you have good tut how to do it link me please.